# kotlin-gradle-plugin 1.6.0 build slow

Tags: kotlin, gradle

When I upgraded the kotlin version from 1.5.30 to 1.6.0, the task of the compilekotlindebug task and kapt was time-consuming, and it was only three minutes away. I get the builid log by using --info.
This part gets called thousands of time and take about 3 mins, while 1.5.30 do not have this problem.

```
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build-types\debug\java', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build\generated\renderscript_source_output_dir\debug\out', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\debug\kotlin', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\debug\kotlin', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\debug\java', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build-types\debug\java', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\main\kotlin', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\main\kotlin', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build-types\debug\java', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build\generated\renderscript_source_output_dir\debug\out', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build-types\debug\java', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build\generated\renderscript_source_output_dir\debug\out', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\debug\kotlin', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\debug\kotlin', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\debug\java', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build-types\debug\java', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\main\kotlin', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\main\kotlin', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build-types\debug\java', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build\generated\renderscript_source_output_dir\debug\out', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build-types\debug\java', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build\generated\renderscript_source_output_dir\debug\out', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\debug\kotlin', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\debug\kotlin', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\debug\java', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build-types\debug\java', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\main\kotlin', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\src\main\kotlin', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build-types\debug\java', not found
file or directory 'F:\ProjectSample\android\sdk\build\generated\renderscript_source_output_dir\debug\out', not found
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a known regression in compilation speed for Android projects introduced in Kotlin `1.6.0`, see [KT-49910](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49910).
Maybe that's what you're affected by?

There also is a workaround provided in the above issue, namely:

```kotlin
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Must go before the real KGP plugin!
    classpath("dev.zacsweers:kgp-160-patcher:1.0.0")
  }
}
```

This will be fixed in the upcoming release `1.6.10`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait until 1.6.10 is released and test it.

Comment: I didn't have this output but yes the compilation is atleast 2x - 3x slower than 1.5.x. Downgrading solved it.